# Reload all tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

My question is quite simple. I'm currently developing a google chrome Extension and I wanted to know how i can reload all the page. Must i use the chrome API or jquery API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easier solution using only background page:

```
chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, function(tabs) {
    for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {url: tabs[i].url});
    }
});
```

Comment: "Deprecated since Chrome 33. Please use tabs.query {windowId: windowId}." SOURCE: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getAllInWindows

You could replace the top line of code with `chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {`